# How to create a cursor loop making it loop X amount of times, concatenating with data from a column

Tags: mysql

Hello again and back for something that may be impossible or just simple and I have over complicated this exponentially.

What I am attempting to do and from what I understand is that I will require to put together a loop and are not very educated on cursors and loops in MySQL.

What I am trying to do is:

This is the data.

```
To construct 6 Unit Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 1-6; Building 10)  
Unit 1,  14751 - 125 STREET NW
```

The first line is what happened, so to construct 6 unit dwellings, I want it to loop 6 times (6 dwellings)
then concat 'Unit', 'house_num' <-- which is from the details in the brackets, Units 1-6), 'street'

So what I want is an output that looks like this:

```
Unit 1,  14751 - 125 STREET NW, To construct 6 Unit Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 1-6; Building 10)  
Unit 2,  14751 - 125 STREET NW, To construct 6 Unit Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 1-6; Building 10)  
Unit 3,  14751 - 125 STREET NW, To construct 6 Unit Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 1-6; Building 10)  
Unit 4,  14751 - 125 STREET NW, To construct 6 Unit Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 1-6; Building 10)  
Unit 5,  14751 - 125 STREET NW, To construct 6 Unit Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 1-6; Building 10)  
Unit 6,  14751 - 125 STREET NW, To construct 6 Unit Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 1-6; Building 10)
```

This is what I have so far... and I just can't seem to find the next steps.  Please kindly, help... an explanation would be wonderful as well as I would very very very much like to not only learn how this works, but to understand this as well.  Thank you!

```
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test$$
    CREATE PROCEDURE test()
    BEGIN
   -- declared values as I had forgotten this, was previously set to default 0 on count... which was maybe why I kept getting 0 back...
       DECLARE count INT;
       DECLARE units_add INT;
    -- Input how many times to loop the procedure 
       WHILE count < units_add 
       DO
/**output should be: 02/permit_number/001.. Unit 1,2,3 etc and address**/

            SELECT Concat('02/', permit_number, '/', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0')),

        Concat('Unit ', 
               COUNT, 
               ', ',
               RIGHT(address, Length(address) - Locate(',', (address )) - 0))
        FROM permits_prep
        WHERE job_descr like '%To construct%';

    -- setting the Unit number start count
          SET count = house_num + 1;

       END WHILE;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

After this... I am lost...

i get this back....

```
> 02/100516029-008/000  Unit 0,  14751 - 125 STREET NW
> 02/100516029-009/000  Unit 0,  14751 - 125 STREET NW
> 02/100516029-010/000  Unit 0,  14751 - 125 STREET NW
> 02/100516029-011/000  Unit 0,  14751 - 125 STREET NW
> 02/100516029-016/000  Unit 0,  14751 - 125 STREET NW
> 02/100516029-017/000  Unit 0,  14751 - 125 STREET NW
> 02/100516029-018/000  Unit 0,  14751 - 125 STREET NW
> 02/100516029-019/000  Unit 0,  14751 - 125 STREET NW
> 02/101151068-006/000  Unit 0,  14220 - YELLOWHEAD TRAIL NW
> 02/101384288-003/000  Unit 0,  11246 - 122 STREET NW
> 02/102010513-004/000  Unit 0,  10345 - 107 STREET NW
> 02/104497468-023/000  Unit 0,  3625 - 144 AVENUE NW
> 02/104497468-024/000  Unit 0,  3625 - 144 AVENUE NW
> 02/104497468-025/000  Unit 0,  3625 - 144 AVENUE NW
> 02/104497468-026/000  Unit 0,  3625 - 144 AVENUE NW
```

My unit numbers aren't increasing by 1, and it is not looping the requested, 6 times....

permits_prep

```
CREATE VIEW permits_prep 
    AS
    SELECT Concat('02/', permit_number)      as id, 
       permit_number        as permit_num, 
       permit_date          as permit_date, 
       job_description      as job_descr,
       LEFT(address, Length(address) - Locate(',', REVERSE(address )) - 1)     as house_num,   
       address              as address, 
       legal_description    as legal_description, 
       floor_area           as floor_area, 
       units_added          as units_add, 
       construction_value   as Constr_val, 
       RIGHT(address, Length(address) - Locate('-', (address )) - 1) as street, 
       latitude             as lattitude, 
       longitude            as longitude, 
       location             as location, 
       neighborhood.nbhrd_id            as neighborhood_id, 
       neighborhood.CITY_city_id        as city_id 
FROM   edmonton_upto_10may2016_mostly_text 
       INNER JOIN neighborhood 
               ON neighbourhood = nbhrd_desc 
    WHERE address LIKE '%,%'
GROUP  BY permit_number, 
          address 
ORDER  BY permit_number;
```

And here is a sample of the data (the main focal point anyways):

```
job_descr                                                              house_num        address
To construct 6 Unit Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 1-6; Building 10)  1   1, 14751 - 125 STREET NW
To construct 7 Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 7-13 - Building 16)     7   7, 14751 - 125 STREET NW
To construct 6 Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 14-19 - Building 4).    19  19, 14751 - 125 STREET NW
To construct 8 Dwellings of Row Housings (UNITS 20-27 - Building 3).    27  27, 14751 - 125 STREET NW
To construct 7 Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 58-64 - Building 8).    58  58, 14751 - 125 STREET NW
To construct 4 Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 65-68 - Building 9)     65  65, 14751 - 125 STREET NW
To construct 7 Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 69-75 - Buiding 15).    69  69, 14751 - 125 STREET NW
To construct 8 Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 76-83 - Building 14)    76  76, 14751 - 125 STREET NW
```

Comment: What is this doing: `SET count = LEFT(permits_prep.address, Length(permits_prep.address) - Locate(',', REVERSE(permits_prep.address )) - 1) + 1;`? Also, could you post the table definition for `permits_prep`?

Comment: oh yes I apologize.  So that statement grabs the number I want to start at.  In this example, from here: 
To construct 6 Unit Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 1-6; Building 10)
Unit 1, 14751 - 125 STREET NW
I wanted to grab the number right before the comma.  so 1.  (I apologize that the word "Unit" is not there in the original data.) To start off with.  It is not always a 1, could be a different number but I want to keep that as the starting number, then add 1 to it as it loops and stops the requested amount of times.  
I have edited above to show permits_prep.  Thank you!

Comment: Is that calculation different from the calculated column `permits_prep.house_num`? Does `permits_prep.units_add` contain the number of times to print?

Comment: it is the same value as permits_prep.house_num.  At the time I did not add the column but I have now and updated that accordingly.  And yes to your second question >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I'm fairly sure this will do what you want:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS list_permits;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS permits_temp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS permits_temp
  (lineid INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
   permit VARCHAR(512));

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE list_permits()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT;

    DECLARE v_id VARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE v_house_num INT;
    DECLARE v_units_add INT;
    DECLARE v_street_address VARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE v_job_descr VARCHAR(256);

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE permits CURSOR FOR
      SELECT id, house_num, units_add,
             RIGHT(address, Length(address) - Locate(',', REVERSE(address )) - 1) AS street_address,
             job_descr
        FROM permits_prep
        WHERE job_descr like '%To construct%';

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
      FOR NOT FOUND
        SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN permits;

    read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH permits INTO
        v_id, v_house_num, v_units_add, v_street_address, v_job_descr;
      IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;
      SET count = 0;
      WHILE count < v_units_add DO
        INSERT INTO permits_temp
            (permit)
          VALUES
            (CONCAT('Unit ', (v_house_num + count), ', ', v_street_address, ', ', v_job_descr));
        SET count = count + 1;
      END WHILE;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE permits;

  -- To retrieve the result, execute
  --  SELECT permit FROM permits_temp ORDER BY lineid;

  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Note that the `DELIMITER` clause is not SQL but rather is specific to the `mysql` command-line client and MySQL Workbench; other clients may not understand it.

Ideally, this would be a "set-returning function" but, alas, MySQL doesn't provide those. Instead we must create a temporary table to hold and return the result. A temporary table is local to the current session, so multiple users can run this procedure concurrently without conflict, and the temporary table is automatically dropped when the session ends.

**HOW IT WORKS:** We begin with the declarations. [The order of these is important](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html): you declare all variables first, followed by conditions (we have none of those here), followed by cursors, followed by condition handlers.

`count` is used to control the **`WHILE`** loop (explained in a moment), the `v_*` variables will hold valued read from the cursor, and `done` will flag when we've run out of data to process.

The basic idiom for cursors is to **`DECLARE`** the cursor (this associates the cursor name with a **`SELECT`** statement), **`OPEN`** the cursor (this *executes* the **`SELECT`** and creates a result set), **`FETCH`** and process one record at a time from the result set until no more records exist, and then **`CLOSE`** the cursor to free up resources.

In this application we need to read `permits_prep` one row at a time, and for each row generate `X` rows of output; for this we use nested loops. The outer **`LOOP`** will execute "forever" until we run out of rows to fetch, at which point we break out of the loop with a **`LEAVE`** statement. We **`FETCH`** each row and then set up the inner **`WHILE`** loop to produce the required number of output rows. (You could also use a **`FOR`** here, but IMHO a **`WHILE`** looks cleaner.)

Calling **`SELECT`** without an **`INTO`** clause causes the procedure to build up a result set that will be returned to the calling code.

*After* we've `FETCH`ed the last row from the cursor, the *next* call to **`FETCH`** will cause the **`NOT FOUND`** handler to be executed, setting `done` to **`TRUE`**, and in turn causing the **`LEAVE`** statement to break out of the outer loop.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes please if you could explain the syntax so that I may better understand the logic and placement, that would be wonderful thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!  Hopefully I can find some examples to practice on.  On a side note, I attempted to run the code however nothing happens.  There are no errors etc, read it through and I understand it maybe an SQL to MySQL crossing happening?

Comment: @Erilyn I just spotted a syntax error (missing `END IF`), and we might have to shove the results into a temp table after all. Let me work on it a little more and get back to you.

Comment: @Erilyn I've added a temporary table to hold the result for further processing. I think it should work now.

Comment: Hmmmm... still does not retrieve anything.. not sure whats happening?  I am going to try and research some more of these loops.. I understand what you wrote and how its put together but I bet this is a syntax missing or something.  It works and runs but it retrieves nothing

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an easier way to do what you need:

- Create a temporary table
- Store as many values you need
- Query on that temporary table:

Something like this:

```sql
delimiter $$
create procedure myProc(n int)
begin
    drop table if exists temp_values;
    create temporary table temp_values(int val, index idx_val(val));
    set @i = 0;
    store_values: repeat
        set @i = @i + 1;
        insert into temp_values values(@i);
    until @i >= n end repeat;
end $$
delimtier ;
```

And then simply execute the procedure and do your `select`:

```
call myProc(6);
select replace('Unit XXX,  14751 - 125 STREET NW, To construct 6 Unit Dwellings of Row Housings (Units 1-6; Building 10)', 'XXX', v.val)
from temp_values as v
order by v.val;
```

This should give you the output you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I will try it out and let you know how it goes!